# Python - double backslash in Windows path when using subprocess.call()

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, backslash

I can't get this code to work.

```
subprocess.call([os.path.normpath(
                   os.path.dirname(
                     os.path.realpath(
                       sys.argv[0]))) + '\mscgen.exe', 
                 '  -T png ' + os.path.normpath(
                                 os.path.dirname(
                                   os.path.realpath(
                                     args.mscInputFilePath)))])
```

where

```
sys.argv[0] == 'D:/Python/mscFromLog/msgFromLog.py'
args.mscInputFilePath == 'D:\\Python\\mscFromLog\\log_files\\my_file.signalling'
```

which, given my (probably wrong) use of `normpath`, `dirname`, and `realpath`, expand to the following paths:

```
'D:\\Python\\mscFromLog\\mscgen.exe'
'D:\\Python\\mscFromLog\\log_files'
```

I suspect that passing those double backslashes to Windows is a problem. It certainly chokes on

```
dir D:\\Python\\mscFromLog\\mscgen.exe
```

Note that appending `.replace('\\\\', '\\')` did not help.

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n',
'  File "D:/Python/mscFromLog/msgFromLog.py", line 248, in GenerateMsc\n
    subprocess.call([os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))) + \'\\\\mscgen.exe\', \'  -T png \' + os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(args.mscInputFilePath)))])\n',
'  File "D:\\Python\\Interpreter\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 560, in call\n
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:\n',
'  File "D:\\Python\\Interpreter\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__\n
    restore_signals, start_new_session)\n',
'  File "D:\\Python\\Interpreter\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child\n
    startupinfo)\n',
'  File "D:\\Programs\\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\\helpers\\pydev\\pydev_monkey.py", line 299, in new_CreateProcess\n
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(appName, patch_arg_str_win(commandLine), *args)\n',
'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified\n']
```

Comment: It should be double back-slash in `'\mscgen.exe'`

Comment: Or use raw string: `r'\mscgen.exe'`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Since `\m` is not a recognized escape sequence, it is [left unchanged](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) in the string, so the problem is not here.

Comment: Even as of Python 3.5 `os.path.realpath` has yet to be implemented on Windows; it's still just `abspath` by another name. Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), e.g. `str(pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).parent.resolve() / 'mscgen.exe')`. Remove the `resolve` call if you don't care about resolving reparse points (i.e. symbolic links, junctions) to get the real path.

Comment: The ``\\`` that you see is just the repr. After reflowing your subprocess call I see that the list should be `[some_path, '-T', 'png', some_other_path]`. But that shouldn't interfere with finding the executable, so confirm that `D:\Python\mscFromLog\mscgen.exe` actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Appending `.__str__()` to string paths that contain delimited backslashes should do the trick.

For example:
`args.mscInputFilePath.__str__()`

Intuitively, that method gives you what you see when you call `print()` on something, and is the answer to the occasional desire on Windows where you may wish you could store the result of printing a string object.  There are good posts on the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` for more context.

Comment: (A little late on this answer to say the least, but I had a similar issue today and eventually figured it out thanks to a tip from a colleague.)

Comment: And was teh answer as given above?

Comment: It does not fix the problem, I'd say Popen is at some point triggering __str__ or __repr__ doubling the \.